# yii2 сохранение формы по ajax [Решено]

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2, mvc

Есть форма. Есть модель и таблица в БД. Есть контроллер. КАК принять и сохранить данные Data=$(this).serialize(); переданные ajax???

Помогите, пожалуйста с контроллером. Обычным постом всё прекрасно работает. А с аяксом беда.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неожиданно нашлось решение. Так и не понял, в чём дело. Если отправлять запрос вот так (ниже), то всё ок - данные приходят на сервер в виде масива.

```
jQuery('#peoples_form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var peopleData=$(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/site/add-new-people',
        async: async,
        timeout: 20000,
        dataType: datatype,
        data: peopleData,
        success: function(result){console.log(result);},
        error: function(err){console.log(err);}
    });
});
```

Но если отсылать вот так (аякс вынесен как функция)

```
jQuery('#peoples_form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var peopleData=$(this).serialize();
    aj('/site/add-new-people', {'peopleData': peopleData});
});

function aj(url1, data, async='false', datatype='html') {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url1,
        async: async,
        timeout: 20000,
        dataType: datatype,
        data: data,
        success: function(result){console.log(result);},
        error: function(err){console.log(err);}
    });
}
```

То данные прилетают не в виде массива, а в виде строки вида

```
_csrf=vk2P3oAnKy855oOydhIt_xcX6ZFuHp1t3AJkGg9eFTlv3-2I0kuToH7bBm3V32uvZFnLhu8-UCkp99pmEv7qug%3D%3D&People%5Bsurname%5D=111&People%5Bfirst_name%5D=&People%5Bmiddle_name%5D=&People%5Bbirth_year%5D=121&People%5Bissue_date%5D=&People%5Bissued_by%5D=&People%5Bpassport_number%5D=111&People%5Bregistration%5D=&People%5Bgender%5D=111&People%5Bclient_note%5D=
```

Которую я всё никак не мог запихнуть в модель. Проблема, похоже, решена. Но причина мне не ясна. Видно, это связано с тем, что вторы способом я передавал данные в функцию как json.

Осталась одна странность - если перезагрузить страницу и отправить форму, то ajax почему-то срабатывает дважды. После этого (до перезагрузки) как и положено - один раз. Решено - нужно js вешать не на событие `submit`, а `on('beforeSubmit', 'form#peoples_form', function (e)` и в конце добавить обязательно `return false`;

Comment: @kizoso какой ссылке? Тут нет никаких ссылок

Comment: Это было стандартное авто сообщение, означающее, что в ответе не содержится ответа. Вы можете ответить на свой собственный вопрос. Перенесите часть с ответом из вопроса сюда.

Comment: @n.osennij `aj('/site/add-new-people', peopleData);` - вот и вся разница

Answer (score 1):

Если, как я понял, проблема именно в приеме данных, и ты просто не можешь их увидеть в $_POST или $_REQUEST, то попробуй такой прием:

```
$request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true)
```

Если не то, уточни и я дополню ответ

Comment: Решение нашлось. Но почему так - я не знаю. Дополнил вопрос. Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой пример:

```
class ExampleController extends Controller
{
    public function actionAjax()
    {
        $post = Yii::$app->request->post();
        var_dump($post);
    }
}
```

Аяксом отсылаете данные на `/example/ajax` и получаете то что отправили. Всё должно быть просто. Если подобный вариант не срабатывает - значит проблема гораздо глубже. Возможно не хватает каких то базовых модулей и компонентов yii.

Comment: Решение нашлось. Но почему так - я не знаю. Дополнил вопрос. Спасибо за ответ!